# Proof of knowledge of big message

Tags: protocol-design

Say party A wants to prove that it has seen the entirety of a public, big message `m`. Providing the hash of `m` is not good enough, because a third party could provide A with the hash. IIUC, signing the message with A's private key would be in principe ok, but most/all signature schemes work by first hashing `m`, so then again, a third party could provide the hash, and then A signs it. So this only proves that A knows the hash, not the entire `m`.

Are there light (no ZK), non-interactive protocol to achieve this? Non-interactive in the sense that I'd like to avoid A being challenged. But it's ok to use several steps, with a sort of commit-reveal scheme for instance.

Comment: Any information that A may exchange towards the desired proof can be relayed from/to another party that actually holds `m`. Under standard crypto hypothesis we have to accept that. Thus the stated reason why _"providing the hash of `m` is not good enough"_ is dubious. I prefer these two 1) the hash proves something only to one who knows it, or how to verify it. 2) Ability to compute the SHA-512 of message `m` implies at least availability of the whole `m` at the time of the computation, but that could be past knowledge; the file itself could already be lost forever, or never stored in full.

Comment: Knowing the SHA512 hash of $m$ doesn't imply that anyone held $m$ in its entirety at a single point in time, because SHA512 can be computed in one pass over the data.

Comment: You might be looking for a [proof of retrievability](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/073) or [proof of data possession](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dawnsong/papers/2011%20remote%20data%20checking.pdf)

Comment: You mentioned that `m` is 'big'. Please specify the maximum acceptable time a modern CPU should take to produce or verify the proof, for a specified size of `m`.